# __webpack_require__(...).platform is not a function

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, electron

I am using Electron + React JS + NodeJS to make a desktop application to start and stop backend process.

For this purpose I have to use both import and require in same file for that purpose I have write this code:

```
import Module from "module";
const requires = Module.createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

I am getting this error:

```
__webpack_require__(...).platform is not a function
TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).platform is not a function
at ./node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob-parent/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11377:95)
at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84571:31)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84016:33)
at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84228:21)
at ./node_modules/glob-stream/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10815:18)
at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84571:31)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84016:33)
at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84228:21)
at ./node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78489:10)
at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84571:31)
```

I want to use both require and import in same file so that I can use React JS with Node JS
Thanks.

Comment: Using NodeJS in the renderer is a [security risk](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content), use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

Comment: Thanks @Arkellys for your comment
I Think I am using webpack rerenderer , am new to NodeJS and webpack. 
Actually, I am using @whiskeysockets/baileys for whatsapp chat. And I want to create a desktop application where user just click single button which start the connections with whatsapp and display connection status, UI React JS part are completed with Electron. But When I integrate NodeJS part I am getting this error. I have tried many solutions but does not work.

Comment: Have you read the docs I sent? Try to solve your issue following the examples. If you are still stuck after that, update your question with your attempts.

Comment: Special Thanks @Arkellys, Actually, I was trying to run NodeJS on the browser.

Now it's is resolved

Comment: I'm glad you solved your issue. I will vote to close your question as duplicate, since it's a common problem.